# running mountd with compiled rpcbind

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to run mountd with my own compiled version of rpcbind. If I have rpcbind running in debug mode (`./rpcbind -d`) before I start mountd, I get the following error message:

```
/etc/rc.d/mountd: WARNING: Unable to force rpcbind. It may already be running.
/etc/rc.d/mountd: WARNING: failed precmd routine for mountd
```

If I do not have rpcbind running when I start mountd, then it starts the rpcbind that is installed on the system and not my compiled version.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to run mountd by hand, instead of using the rc script.  Just do "mountd", as root.